# Python: Extract attributes from a self-closing element with same name as other elements

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I need to extract some, I think attribute values (sorry I don't know XML terminology that well) from some XML contained with elements that have the same names.

I've been using xpath parsing with the xml.etree.ElementTree library, but I keep getting null values.

this is an example of the XML:

```
<parent>
 <child tag1="spam" tag2="1" tag3="some url" />
 <child tag1="spam" tag2="2" tag3="another url" />
 <child tag1="spam" tag2="3" tag3="yet another url" />
 <child tag1="spam" tag2="4" tag3="the last url" />
```

I am trying to extract the url from the 3rd child tag, where tag2="3"

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

r=requests.get(url, user, password) #from another .py file I made for this use
tree=ET.fromstring(r.content)
desired_out=tree.findall('.//child/..[@tag2="3"]')
print(desired_out)
```

the requests.get execution works for all other fields in the XML when I try to extract it, but I seem to be having some problem with the xpath.

Expected output should be the URL, or at least some indication of it being stored in memory, instead I get [].

Thank you for any help.

---

I got it sorted. For whatever reason the xpath options didn't work for me, so I just did a few for loops and an if statement to get what I needed.

````
```python
for lmnt in root.findall(parent, namespace):
    for grandchild in lmnt.findall(child, namespace):
        tags = grandchild.attrib[tag2_attrib]
            if tags == '3':
                url = grandchild.attrib[tag3_attrib]
```
````

returns the URL in a string format. Thanks for the replies though, appreciate the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this xpath

```
.//child[@tag2="3"]/@tag3
```

Comment: I tried this but got an error "SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element"

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to convert XML to `dict` with [xmltodict](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/):

```
import xmltodict

data = '''<parent>
 <child tag1="spam" tag2="1" tag3="some url" />
 <child tag1="spam" tag2="2" tag3="another url" />
 <child tag1="spam" tag2="3" tag3="yet another url" />
 <child tag1="spam" tag2="4" tag3="the last url" />
</parent>'''

result = xmltodict.parse(data)['parent']['child'][2]['@tag3']
```

Output:

```
yet another url
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the tag2 value, I want the URL that follows tag2. Also it's XML from a webpage/API call, not a file, but I'll see if I can give it a go by adjusting your code to fit.